# Django lack detail of error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

`Django` is not giving me detailed information about the error.

For example when I get `ImportError`, I can not see where the error is comming from. Which file which line. It only gives me `ImportError: cannot import name ___`. But it is not enough to find where the error is.  It is not only about `ImportError`.Many error is given to me with lack of detail like that. I am really bored with searching where is the error and it takes my time.

Is there a way to make it to give me more information about error in DJango.

I am using `python==2.7` and `django==1.5.3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `DEBUG = True` in your settings.py and start your server with `python manage.py runserver --traceback`

Comment: --traceback was my answer.